# How to stop previous song after clicking next images by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am Trying to make a simple game like there are so many animals images are there. I want to play a song after clicking on images. I have done that. But problem is after clicking next images the first images song should be stop then next image song will be continued. Here is the sample cide

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Anmal Sounds</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
     function myAudioFunction(letter) {
        var audio = new Audio('C:\\Users\\SONU\\Desktop\\animal\\'+letter+'.mp3');
         audio.play();
     }
    </script>
    <a onclick="myAudioFunction('tiger');">
     <img src="C:\Users\SONU\Desktop\animal\tiger.jpeg" height="110px" width="110px">
    </a>
    <a onclick="myAudioFunction('cat');">
     <img src="C:\Users\SONU\Desktop\animal\cat.jpg" height="110px" width="110px">
    </a>
    <a onclick="myAudioFunction('elephant');">
     <img src="C:\Users\SONU\Desktop\animal\elephant.jpg" height="110px" width="110px">
    </a>
    <a onclick="myAudioFunction('deer');">
     <img src="C:\Users\SONU\Desktop\animal\deer.jpg" height="110px" width="110px">
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

`when I click next images the 1st I ages song still continued. But how to stop previous one and play next one`

1. Anyone has any idea

   ```
    How to solve this problem.
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution you need to put audio object outside like below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var audio = new Audio();
     function myAudioFunction(letter) {
        audio.pause()
        audio = new Audio('C:\\Users\\SONU\\Desktop\\animal\\'+letter+'.mp3');
         audio.play();
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `audio.pause()` before you reassign the `audio` variable?

This command may return an error the first time it's done, since audio hasn't been declared yet, but you can fix that by doing `if(audio) audio.pause()`.